# Fullcalendar how to change validRange grayed days color?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, fullcalendar

Greetings I am using fullcalendar v.5.10.1 for my project and I want to change already passed days color to more grayish(see picture)/ I cannot use Ajax only CSS styles. What styles I need to apply to make (marked) colons be more grayed or complete different color?
[image]

Already tested and it is not working if adding this styles to calendars CSS overwriting its CSS styles

```css
.fc-past{background-color:red;}

.fc-day-past{background-color:red;}

.fc-past {background-color: purple;}

.fc-day-thu{background-color:red}
```

btw as option I pass to fullcalendar, validRange parameter
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey I found the solution. To change `grayed` fields if you are using validRange as option. need to change this styles

```
.fc .fc-cell-shaded,
.fc .fc-day-disabled {
  background: #E5E5E5;
  background: #E5E5E5;
}
```